# How to populate Listview in flutter using multiple views

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am able show vertical and horizontal list in single list but the problem is that duplicate items are showing i want in first horizontal list for e.g 4 items the vertical list also i want 4 item and after in next horizontal list i want next 4 four items till the list not ends please help me for this.

```
class mydynamic extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_mydynamicState createState() => _mydynamicState();
}

class _mydynamicState extends State<mydynamic> {
  Future<List<model>> getdata() async {
var data = await http.get("https://webrooper.com/androiddb/foodlist.php");

var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
print(jsonData);

List<model> foodlist = [];

for (var i in jsonData) {
  model modelist = model(i["title"], i["price"], i["imgurl"]);
  foodlist.add(modelist);
}

return foodlist;
}

Widget buildCard(String text) {
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
  child: Text(text),
);
}

 Widget buildHorizontalList(AsyncSnapshot snapshot, int index) {
return SizedBox(
  height: 200.0,
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        child: Card(
          child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].imgurl),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}

 Widget buildVerticalList(AsyncSnapshot snapshot, int index) {
return ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      child: Card(
        child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].imgurl),
      ),
    );
  },
);
}

 @override
 void dispose() {
 super.dispose();
 }

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      "Videolist",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: getdata(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data == null) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: getdata(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return index.isEven
                    ? buildHorizontalList(snapshot, index)
                    : buildVerticalList(snapshot, index);
              },
            );
          },
        );
    },
  ),
);}}
```

The above code is my sample code please help me for this Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post some sample data. You might post some image or any so that it would be helpful.

Comment: Sir when i am using list under a list this is working fine `List<List<String>> lists = [
    ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"],
    ["B1", "B2", "B3"],
    ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"],
    ["D1", "D2", "D3"],
    ["F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5"],
    ["B1", "B2", "B3"],
    ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"],
    ["D1", "D2", "D3"]
  ];`

Comment: So i want to add my Api data List inside list

Comment: Sir please see this code [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KMYuMY2gwF28csLeAoDiDhQOxvtHyiXq?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can try something like this. And adapt your `buildHorizontalList`and `buildVerticalList`to accept a list as parameter.

```
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {

           if(index%4 == 0){
      
             if(index.isEven){

                return buildHorizontalList(snapshot.data.sublist(index, index+4));
      
             }else{

                return buildVerticalList(snapshot.data.sublist(index+4, index+8));
             }

          } else {
             if(index+4 > list.length)
               return buildVerticalList(snapshot.data.sublist(index));
          },
        );
```

To use the code above you need to change your methods `buildHorizontalList`and `buildVerticalList` like this. Instead of AsyncSnapshot you must pass a List, and you can remove the index parameter also.

```
Widget buildHorizontalList(List<Model> listModel) {
return SizedBox(
  height: 200.0,
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: listModel.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        child: Card(
          child: Image.network(listModel[index].imgurl),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
```

Here is a simple example, that you can test at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
void main() {
  
  var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'];
  
  for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    if(i%4 == 0){
      
      if(i.isEven){
        print(list.sublist(i, i+4));
      
      }else{
        print(list.sublist(i+4, i+8));
      }
    } else {
      if(i+4 > list.length)
      print(list.sublist(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try sir Thank you can you see my code [code_link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KMYuMY2gwF28csLeAoDiDhQOxvtHyiXq)

Comment: I edited my answer. But did you tried my example? You need to change your ListView.builder inside your widget build method.

Comment: Sir its showing only horizontal list [screenshot](https://ibb.co/qpwNdfK)

Comment: Sir your code working sir but one problem its giving error for range error `RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in range 6..7, inclusive: 8` please solve for me thank you :)

Comment: This occurs when your list length isn't a multiple of 4. To fix this you must create the last sublist with the remaining items from the list. I edited my answer. You can see at the simple example also, to see the result.